# how add react component in tampermonkey script?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tampermonkey, userscripts

Can you just give an example of embedding a react component with its hsk markup in a tampermonk script? Suitable even for creating:

```
<div> Hello </div>
```

I try:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @match        https://www.google.com/*
// @require      https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js
// @require      https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

(function () {
  'use strict';

  const { useState } = React;

  function MyComponent() {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    return (
      <div>
        <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
        <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Click me</button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  const div = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(div);

  ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, div);
})();
```

But everything i get error:

```
caught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' 
(at userscript.html?name=React%2520inside%2520js.user.js&id=1d53c973-bea2-49fc-bdbb-6ab45375a6b1:302:7)VM
```

Comment: You need to use babel to transform jsx to js. You can also write react code without jsx

Comment: how add babel in tampermonkey?